# Is there any tool to generate Watin page objects from a given web page?

Tags: automated-tests, watin

WatiN looks nice, but generating page objects by hand seems very tedious.

Is there any browser plugin or other tool that would allow me to click a few elements (form fields, divs, etc) and export the source of a page object for these elements? It looks like an obvious addition to the framework.

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: maybe you can also tag this question with webdriver selenium, watir tags to get more response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this blogpost.

http://slmoloch.blogspot.com/2009/12/design-of-selenium-tests-for-aspnet.html

It discusses a mixture of the xpather tool and T4 templates to autogenerate pageobjects. Its also a nice series on how to setup a selenium environment for .Net, most of the things are also applicable for Watin tests.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It's not really what I am looking for, but the article series does look interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I've been curious about Page Object generation as well.  However, instead of having to load a browser and click around like a recorder, I was thinking of discovering the pages and controls through reflection of the web app dll.

I have not heard of a tool that does this, but I'm just putting this out there in case you wanted to spend a little bit of time to discover and generate the code exactly they way you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about the WatiN Test Recorder?

http://watintestrecord.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Sorry, but I can't tell anymore. It's been a while since I had a look at WatiN and in the end I chose Selenium.